# PHP showing certain content top of page, rest afterwards

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress team members have a select in admin that lets you pick a number to display the team in a certain order on Archive page. The Select returns a value of the number, which i retrieve.

However, I want to display all the members that have the value of 1 first, and any members after that show up below. At the moment, the IF statements only shows the content if they exist (obviously), i would like to however make it work somehow so it shows Members with value 1 first, then members with value 2. Thank you!

```
$images = get_field('image');
$titles = get_the_title();
$positions = get_field('position');
$link = get_permalink($post->ID);

if ($positions[0] == 1) {
    echo "<div class='employee'>";
    echo "<img src='$images'>";
    echo "<h2>$titles</h2>";
    echo "</div>";
}

if ($positions[0] == 2) {
    echo "<div class='employee'>";
    echo "<img src='$images'>";
    echo "<h2>$titles</h2>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: please include your code in the question instead of posting a picture

Comment: First time using this, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: you can use `array_sort` i think to sort the positions array if thats what you want

Comment: No, I want to write code that displays team members that have value of 1 first, and then team members that have value of 2 etc. at the moment, team members with value of 3 are at the top of the page

Comment: is members an array? it's still a bit unclear what you wan't as the result

Comment: I don’t have a members array. I have a positions array that has a value between 1-9, inside my if statesmen’s I have the code that displays the information of the team member that has the corresponding value. However, if you look at my code, I want all positions == 1 information to be placed first on the page, and positions == 2 second

Comment: could it be the code you showed is part of another loop? and can you show that code as well?

Comment: It’s a Wordpress custom post type, that I’m getting the images and links from, this code is the only code that has to do with the team

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the $positions array you could use

```
sort($positions);
```

Comment: Certain team members have value of 1, others 2. I want to display members with value 1 first, then 2. At the moment, members with 2 displays before 1

Answer (score 0):

You you can easily sort by a meta value with get_posts()...

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'team_members',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'position',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC'
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );
?>

<?php if( $posts ): ?>

    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata( $post ) ?>
        <li class='employee'>
            <img src='$images'>
            <h2>$titles</h2>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```